# MVVM & Navigation Framework

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-4.0

I have more of question than a problem at the moment and was looking for advice :

I have an app that redirects the user to the "Owners home page" if they belong to a "Owners" role : Then , the app checks to see if they have an "account" (nothing to do with authentication) which is a collection of personal information similar to a profile.

I have implemted the MVVM pattern so far: Now my experience is running thin because I normally work with commands in the view model tied to click events in the view...

How should I go about keeping view code behind clean and accomodating the conditional redirects that the app needs to implement

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you would still use a vm for the logic of your button command. if the criteria is met you send a message to your nagigation handler that its to move to the proper page. MVVM-Light or parts of prism make this easy. You only need a minor piece of codebehind for the listener where you have your navigation frame and thats it...

Comment: Does that mean I need to implement MVVM Light and / or Prism ?

Comment: You dont have to implement either one, however by implementing MVVMLight it will make it much much more easy to do what you are trying as the plumbing is 99%done for you.